# RX Android Observable.interval() causes OOM

Tags: android, mobile, system.reactive, polling

I should probably start with I'm a newbie in the android RX world. I have a polling method where I use Observable.interval() to poll once a second:

```
Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .timeInterval()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<Timed<Long>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull Timed<Long> longTimed) throws Exception 
                            {
                              presenter.poll()
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

Now this works fine for a while but after I get an out of memory exception. My guess is that I'm creating too many threads very fast and the GC can't purge them in time.

```
1638 W System.err:  at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:366)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectPeriodicTask.run(ScheduledDirectPeriodicTask.java:42)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:307)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:302)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:883)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:975)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1617)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:342)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:579)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:680)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.NewThreadWorker.scheduleActual(NewThreadWorker.java:146)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.IoScheduler$EventLoopWorker.schedule(IoScheduler.java:230)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at io.reactivex.Scheduler.scheduleDirect(Scheduler.java:136)
04-09 09:19:55.634  1543  1638 W System.err:    at io.reactivex.Scheduler.scheduleDirect(Scheduler.java:112)
04-09 09:19:55.635  1543  1638 W System.err:    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn.subscribeActual(SingleSubscribeOn.java:37)
04-09 09:19:55.635  1543  1638 W System.err:    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
04-09 09:19:55.635  1543  1638 W System.err:    at mypackagename.Presenter.poll(Presenter.java:83)
```

Is there any way I could reuse a scheduler? Or manually delete/ close it after I polled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable of Disposable type: So that if we need to stop this then this will be used.

```
Disposable disposable;
```

And after that just follow the code below:

```
disposable = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .doOnNext(t -> YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME())
                    .subscribe();
```

and when you need to stop just use the code below:

```
  if (!disposable.isDisposed()) {
                disposable.dispose();
```

**NOTE: Replace YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME with your function name.**

Comment: Hi @Kamal! Thank you for your answer. If I dispose wouldn't that stop the polling?

Comment: yes, I meant if you need to stop then use   ""if (!disposable.isDisposed()) {
                disposable.dispose();""                                                                                                  otherwise the  ""disposable = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .doOnNext(t -> YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME())
                    .subscribe();""   code will do your work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I will give it a go and let you know.

Comment: Welcome @androidenthusiast, Kindly mark it as the correct answer if it helps you. Thanks in advance.